# Passing 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'?

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode11

When I run the below code, I get a "Passing 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'const char *'" error on this line:

```
int result = strcmp(lowerCase(input), answers[i]);
```

The code that the error is in is:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(questions); i++)
{
    printf("%s", questions[i]);
    scanf("%s", input);

    int result = strcmp(lowerCase(input), answers[i]);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        score++;
    }
}
```

and lowerCase is defined as:

```
void lowerCase(char s[]) {

   int c = 0;

   while (s[c] != '\0') {

      if (s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z') {

          s[c] = s[c] + 32;

      }

      c++;
   }
}
```

The whole code is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>             // strcmp() prototype is in here.
#include <ctype.h>

char *questions[3];
char *answers[3];

void fillQuestions(void);
void fillAnswers(void);

void lowerCase(char []);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    fillQuestions();
    fillAnswers();

    char input[80];
    int score = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(questions); i++)
    {
        printf("%s", questions[i]);
        scanf("%s", input);


        int result = strcmp(lowerCase(input), answers[i]);
        if (result == 0)
        {
            score++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tSCORE: %d\n\n", score);

    return 0;
}

void fillQuestions()
{
    questions[0] = "The famous basketball player Dr. J original name is what?";

}

void fillAnswers()
{
    answers[0] = "Julius Erving";

}

void lowerCase(char s[]) {

   int c = 0;

   while (s[c] != '\0') {

      if (s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z') {

          s[c] = s[c] + 32;

      }

      c++;
   }

}
```

I am using XCode 11.3.

Comment: You can't pass the value returned by a function that doesn't return a value onto another function (hence the error message about `void` and `const char *`).  Because `lowerCase()` does not return a value (its return type is `void`), you can't do: `strcmp(lowerCase(input), answers[i]);`.  You'd call `lowerCase(input);` and then ``int result = strcmp(input, answers[i]);``. Alternatively, revise `lowerCase()` so it returns a `char *` and end it with `return s;`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this cleared up the error. However, when I return s;, I get another error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Comment: See the tail section of my updated answer for an explanation (of at least some) of the further problems in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Compiler complaint

You can't pass the value returned by a function that doesn't return a value onto another function (hence the error message about `void` and `const char *`).

Because `lowerCase()` does not return a value (its return type is `void`), you can't do:

```
strcmp(lowerCase(input), answers[i]);
```

You'd use:

```
lowerCase(input);
int result = strcmp(input, answers[i]);
```

Alternatively, revise `lowerCase()` so it returns a `char *` and end it with `return s;` (and then you don't need to change the call to `strcmp()`).

---

#### Rewrite `lowerCase()`

Since you include `<ctype.h>`, you could write:

```c
void lowerCase(char s[])
{
   int c = 0;
   while (s[c] != '\0') {
      if (isupper((unsigned char)s[c])) {
          s[c] = tolower((unsigned char)s[c]);
      }
      c++;
   }
}
```

or:

```c
char *lowerCase(char s[])
{
   for (int c = 0; s[c] != '\0'; c++)
      s[c] = tolower((unsigned char)s[c]);
   return s;
}
```

The casts are necessary in case plain `char` is a signed type.  The [functions from `<ctype.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.4) take an `int` which is either EOF or the value of a character converted to `unsigned char`.

It's not necessary to test whether the character is lower-case; the `tolower()` function leaves anything which is not upper-case unchanged — and additional advantage of using the functions.

---

#### Other problems

You have 3 elements in `questions` and `answers`, but you only initialize one element of each.  When you loop to index 1, you get null pointers — hence `address = 0x0` in the error message.  You tried reading from a null pointer; crashes normally happen after you do that.

Also, `sizeof(questions)` is almost certainly 24 — the number of bytes needed to store three 64-bit pointers.  You need `sizeof(questions) / sizeof(questions[0])` for the loop limit — if you add the extra two questions and answers.

Because you convert the input to all lower-case, you'll never get an input that matches the answer (which is in mixed-case).

The answer string is stored in a string literal.  If you tried to modify the answer with `lowerCase()`, you'd get a crash because string literals are stored in read-only memory.